# extract string and int from a string

Tags: java, string

I have a string : `RoomA38`. I want to extract from it `RoomA` and put in an object of type String, extract `3` and `8` and put them in two different type int.I thought of the method split but I don't know how to use it in this case. How Can i do it?

Comment: Will it always be of the format: `<word><digit><digit>` ?

Comment: yes.it will be always so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```
String myString = "RoomA38";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0;i<myString.length();i++){
    char c = myString.charAt(i);
    if(!Character.isDigit(c)){
        sb.append(c);
    }else{
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(c+""));
    }
}

String roomString = sb.toString();
for(Integer i : numbers){
    //use the number i
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by various way, You just need some calculation there is no any specific api or build in methods.
The below is also a way to do this.

```
    String str = "RoomA38";
    int number = 0;
    String[] strArr = str.split("\\d");
    str = str.replace(strArr[0], "");
    number = Integer.parseInt(str);
    System.out.println("Numbers::: " + number);
    str = strArr[0];
    System.out.println("String is:::: " + str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "RoomA3814221";
    String pattern = "[0-9]+";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);

    String result = sc.findInLine(pattern);

    String[] arr = result.split("");

    System.out.println(result);

    System.out.println(arr.length);

    for (String s: arr) { 
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Scanner for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

using following line, you can find out if a `char` is a digit.
    Character.isDigit('');

you can iterate over each `char` in string and extract the useful chars accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

***You can extract Numbers from a string after that write your own logic to separate numbers also.***

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

if the format is always the same :

```
    String value = "RoomA38";
    String room = value.substring(0, 5);
    Integer floor = Integer.valueOf(value.substring(5,6));
    Integer roomNumber = Integer.valueOf(value.substring(6,7));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use RegEx?

```
@Test
public void splitString() {
    final String src = "RoomA38";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\D*)(\\d*)");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(src);
    matcher.matches();
    final String resultString = matcher.group(1);
    final int resultInt = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
    Assert.assertEquals("RoomA", resultString);
    Assert.assertEquals(38, resultInt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the desired result using regular expression and pattern matching in java

```
String chars;
int result2,result3;
String str= "RoomA38";
String regex ="([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]{1})([0-9]{1})";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( str);
while (matcher.find( ))
{
result = matcher.group(1);  
result2 =Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));  
result3 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3)); 
System.out.println("chars="+result+" "+"number1="+result2+" "+"number2="+result3);                 
}
chars=RoomA number1=3 number2=8
```